# Qmail/popuser Environment Permissions (Linux/CentOS)

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, centos, qmail

I am trying to get a mail-receiving script working, but I am getting a permissions error when it tries to copy files to where I need them.

We're running a Linux/CentOS/Plesk webserver.  I have qmail set to pipe messages that a certain address receives to a shell script.  That script is supposed to write the messages to a file and copy them to one of the server's vhost subscriptions so that they can be accessed by code running via the webserver.

I can get the messages passed to the shell script no problem, and it can successfully write the received message to a file in the local directory (the recipient's folder in /var/qmail/mailnames/).  When the script tries to copy the message file to the correct vhost directory, however, I get a 'permission denied' error.

--

.qmail (file piping mail to parse_mail.sh - included for clarity, this part is working as intended):

```
| true
| /bin/bash parse_mail.sh &> parse_mail_sh.log
```

--

parse_mail.sh:

```
echo "Start parse_mail $(date)";
u=$(/bin/id -u -n);
echo "running as ${u}";
umask 000;
# random tag name
templ='message';
rand=$(awk -vmin=100000000 -vmax=999999999 'BEGIN{srand(); print 
int(min+rand()*(max-min+1))}');
tag=$templ$rand;
echo "Create dir ${tag}/";
/bin/mkdir $tag;
echo "Write message into ${tag}/";
/bin/cp /dev/stdin ${tag}/message.txt;
echo "Copy message to message_files/";
/bin/cp ${tag}/message.txt /var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/${tag}_content.txt
echo "Remove ${tag}/";
/bin/rm -R ${tag};
echo "End parse_mail";
```

--

parse_mail_sh.log log shows:

```
Start parse_mail Thu Jul 18 11:07:06 EDT 2019
running as popuser
Create dir message494556566/
Write message into message494556566/
Copy message to message_files/
/bin/cp: failed to access '/var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/message494556566_content.txt': Permission denied
Remove message494556566/
End parse_mail
```

--

Pretty straight-forward, right? 'popuser' just doesn't have permission to write to this other directory.

Except, here's the odd thing:

I'm not an expert, but I generally understand how unix/linux permissions work.  I believe popuser DOES have the requisite permissions to access and write to the directory - the intervening directory structure is traversable, and I've added popuser to the groups necessary to write to that specific subscription folder.

I can su to popuser in the terminal and cd up and down the directory structure, and copy/create files in the correct places.  I can even run the mail-receiving script from the terminal AS popuser, and it works perfectly.  It only throws the error when triggered on receiving mail.

I assume this means that there is some difference in the environment popuser is operating in via qmail as opposed to the terminal - I just haven't been able to track down exactly what that might be (or find articles online about it).

Or perhaps I misunderstanding how something works?  Like I said, not an expert...

**So my question is:**

Why can't the parse_mail.sh script successfully copy the created file to the indicated message_files/ directory when a message is received by qmail, given that that same script CAN do so when executed by the same system user (popuser) when run via the terminal?

Comment: Can you show me the complete output after executing this line manually `ls -l /var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/message494556566_content.txt’`.

Comment: @mihi - Certainly?

ls: cannot access /var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/message494556566_content.txt: No such file or directory.

I'm not sure I completely understand the question.  My entire problem is that the script cannot create this file.

Comment: Try this then, `mkdir -p /var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files`. Then `touch /var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/test`. This will determine if you have permission to create files in that directory or no. If you have permission, a file named `test` will be created in that dir.

Comment: @mihir : Modified script to contain your test commands.  I can execute the script as 'popuser' in a terminal and it works. HOWEVER, when triggered by the receipt of an email, it does not (log): `Start parse_mail Fri Jul 19 08:58:15 EDT 2019
Testing: create dir
/bin/mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files': Permissi$
Touch test file
touch: cannot touch '/var/www/vhosts/subscription/httpdocs/subfolder/message_files/test': Permission denied
End parse_mail`.  In other words, exactly the same condition as with my other code.

Answer (score 0):

After several days of fighting with this, I discovered the problem.

I had made all of the correct changes, but the system hadn't caught up.

I had restarted various services in PLESK - including the "POP/mail server"- but apparently postfix is not something you can control from there.

**When I stopped and then restarted Postfix, my script suddenly worked.**

My only theory is that perhaps 'popuser' was operating through postfix on an old session that didn't have my user group changes - which might explain why I could perform the operations via a popuser terminal, but the mail processor could not.